# What happened to 160 reputation points that magically show up yesterday within 1 sec and is now gone?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-audit, serial-voting

I know this might be a noob question, but I wish to find the answer. So, yesterday after finishing up a question with user521180, which he accepted and +2 rep, miraculously, seconds afterward I gain 160 rep.  So, I was like, cool, I guess someone voted up my previous answers.  Then around 12 pm ET the 160 miracle reputation points got reverted.  So, what exactly happened?  Did this user521180 got overexcited because of the help I gave him and went "up vote" rampage on all my previous answers or was it a bug?  How exactly does it work on Stack Overflow for tracking stuff like this?

I do not know if it has anything to do with user521180 or not.  All is assumption.

Comment: I can't find any user2348, is that a typo, or did he get deleted? If he got deleted that probably answers your question...

Comment: sorry it was user521180. but just assumption. so if a user gets deleted, then you loose all rep from that user?!?

Comment: @kjy112, yes rep from deleted users is removed.  Edit: During the rare times that your rep is recalculated.

Comment: @jzd Not automatically, though. This is probably just the matter of getting way too many upvotes from one source at once - the rapidity of it will trigger an automatic rep recalc as well as revert the reputation. Comparatively, user deletion will be silent until a recalc is performed.

Comment: Look at Jon Skeet's rep.  Now look at your rep.  Now look at Jon Skeet's rep.  This comment is now diamonds.

Comment: @Will i am a bit confused on your comment

Comment: @kjy112: It's from [this Old Spice ad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owGykVbfgUE)

Comment: i am so confused. really really confused.

Comment: I always thought an user should get a warning (at the top of the screen, like when you earn a badge) the first time that happens to him/her. I was quite confused when it happened to me.

Comment: @Borror0 do you mean the rep-recalc or a comment from @Will? :)

Comment: @Pekka: The rep-recalc.

Comment: @Borror I know. Just pulling Will's leg :)

Comment: i should get two reps for starting this party chat =P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just looked at your user history and found that yes, this is a case of the anti-vote-gaming algorithm kicking in. If user521180 really did upvote you 16 times in a row, that might have been enough to trigger it.

The exact details of the algorithm are not public to prevent gaming.

Comment: that sounds about right.  just kind of bumped, and i could have kept on going w/ daily max rep but stopped, but i didn't earn them.